# Calling Assembly to get Application Name

Tags: .net, vb.net, system.reflection

I have a console application (`MyProgram.EXE`) that references a Utilities assembly.

In my Utilities assembly, I have code that does:

```
Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Dim location As String = asm.Location
Dim appName As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(location)
Conole.WriteLine("AppName is: {0}", appName)
```

When I call it from `MyProgram.EXE`, I receive "`AppName is: Utilities.dll`"

What I want is "`AppName is: MyProgram.EXE`"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wow where did all those br's come from in my edit.

Answer (score 14):

Use `GetEntryAssembly()` instead to get the assembly containing the entry point.

The better way to do it is using `System.Environment.CommandLine` property instead.

Specifically:

```
Dim location As String = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()(0)
Dim appName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(location)
Conole.WriteLine("AppName is: {0}", appName)
```

By the way, you want to use `GetFileName` instead of `GetDirectoryName`

Comment: Why is `System.Environment.CommandLine` better than `GetEntryAssembly()`?

Comment: Because GetEntryAssembly() can return null. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx

Comment: also (per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980202/how-do-i-find-the-current-executable-filename):
"The GetEntryAssembly method also returns null if you are running a WCF service application in debug mode, under IIS. This is, admittedly, a rare situation that only a developer would encounter. – Gravitas Nov 10 '10 at 10:39"

Answer (score 12):

Since it is VB.NET you were asking about, you can extract this information *easily* from the 'My' namespace as shown below:

```
My.Application.Info.AssemblyName
```

Comment: This will also get the assembly of the referenced DLL, not the calling (parent) module.

Answer (score 3):

I use:

```
CallingAppName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly.GetName().Name
```

Answer (score 1):

This is supported all over C#/VB environment.

```cs
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't have access to My.Application, probably because I was in a global class, so I used:

```
AppName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
```