# How do I find the current executable filename?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the name of the current executable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616584/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-executable-in-c)

An executable file loads an external library.
Is there a way for the library to know the calling executable file?

(I would have sworn I saw the answer to this elsewhere, but I can't seem to find it anymore)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

*EDIT:*

As of .NET 6, the recommended approach ([CA1839](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1839)) is to use [`System.Environment.ProcessPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processpath?view=net-6.0#system-environment-processpath)

---

*Original answer:*

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

Comment: This one tends to add ".vhost." in the filename, an issue not present if using System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location (see alternate answer).

Comment: @Contango, that is caused by using "Visual Studio Hosting Process" in VS.

Comment: For unit testing in VS 2012.

ProcessName: vstest.executionengine.x86
ConfigurationFile: C:\TFS\Tests\MyData.Tests.v4.0\bin\Debug\MyData.Tests.v4.0.dll.config
MainModule.FileName: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe
MainModule.ModuleName: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe
FriendlyName: UnitTestAdapter: Running test

Comment: @Kiquenet, yes, in unit tests the current executable is the test runner; what's your point?

Comment: This gives full path to executable, use System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName if you want just the executable file name.

Comment: Old answer, I know, but: this no longer works in .NET Core 3.1 and newer (i.e. .NET 5, 6 etc). More details: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/33525. .

NET 6 even has a newer & "more recommended" approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Environment.ProcessPath?view=net-6.0 (at least, JetBrains Rider suggests this method when you use the above)

Comment: Using 'Environment.ProcessPath' is simpler and faster than 'Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName'. It complies with rule ROSLIN:CA1839 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1839

Comment: @JefersonTenorio indeed, but it didn't exist when I wrote this answer...
I'll edit my answer to mention it.

Answer (score 90):

If you want the executable:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
```

If you want the assembly that's consuming your library (which could be the same assembly as above, if your code is called directly from a class within your executable):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location
```

If you'd like just the file*name* and not the path, use:

```
Path.GetFileName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
```

Comment: GetEntryAssembly could return null if called from unmanaged code.

Comment: I don't believe this doesn't work if the executable is not a .NET application.  For example, IIS spins up worker processes (w3wp.exe) which are unmanaged executables that internally spin up an instance of the CLR which executes managed code.  If you use this from within the managed code I do not believe you will get the path to w3wp.exe.

Comment: @MicahZoltu: GetEntryAssembly returns null in a web application see [GetEntryAssembly for web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277692)

Comment: `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` and `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location` return app **.dll** , expect **.exe**.

Answer (score 42):

In addition to the answers above.

I wrote following test.exe as console application

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  Console.WriteLine(
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
  Console.WriteLine(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
  Console.WriteLine(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
  Console.WriteLine(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location);
}
```

Then I compiled the project and renamed its output to the test2.exe file. The output lines were correct and the same.

But, if I start it in the Visual Studio,  the result is:

> d:\test2.vhost.exe
>
> d:\test2.exe
>
> d:\test2.exe
>
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll

The ReSharper plug-in to the Visual Studio has underlined the

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule
```

as possible System.NullReferenceException. If you look into documentation of the MainModule you will find that this property can throw also NotSupportedException, PlatformNotSupportedException and InvalidOperationException.

The GetEntryAssembly method is also not 100% "safe".
MSDN:

> The GetEntryAssembly method can return null when a managed assembly
>   has been loaded from an unmanaged application. For example, if an
>   unmanaged application creates an instance of a COM component written
>   in C#, a call to the GetEntryAssembly method from the C# component
>   returns null, because the entry point for the process was unmanaged
>   code rather than a managed assembly.

For my solutions, I prefer the `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`.

More interest is if need to solve the problem for the **virtualization**. For example, we have a project, where we use a Xenocode Postbuild to link the .net code into one executable. This executable must be renamed. So all the methods above didn't work, because they only gets the information for the original assembly or inner process.

The only solution I found is

```
var location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
var directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(location);
var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, 
  System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe");
```

Comment: The GetEntryAssembly method also returns null if you are running a WCF service application in debug mode, under IIS. This is, admittedly, a rare situation that only a developer would encounter.

Comment: Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() is null for me, when I use Addin VS 2008. System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule is devenv.exe, but not my DLL with Addin. and I don't know get the Assembly (of Addin) from another assembly that use the addin.

Comment: 1) If A.exe uses B.dll, and B.dll uses C.dll, what's happens if that code is in C.dll ?. 2)
AppDomain can be a EXE application, Web application, Unit test application, Addin Visual Studio, and "Silverlight App"(?). Maybe interesting full solution for all cases.

Answer (score 13):

Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]

Comment: inside `static void Main(string[] args)` this should be the one used. It's weird because from what I remember of C++, the first argument was always the executable.

Answer (score 7):

I think this should be what you want:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
```

This returns the assembly that was first loaded when the process started up, which would seem to be what you want.

`GetCallingAssembly` won't necessarily return the assembly you want in the general case, since it returns the assembly containing the method immediately higher in the call stack (i.e. it could be in the same DLL).

Comment: I'm not sure about GetCallingAssembly() - doesn't that the return the assembly that contains the calling method (one up on the call stack)? This is just as likely to be the library rather than the executable.

Comment: @Martin: Yeah, you're right. GetCallingAssembly may work/be appropiate in some cases, but it seems he wants GetEntryAssembly here.

Answer (score 3):

`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`

Answer (score 2):

There is also:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath;
```

Comment: It always seemed dumb to me that the Forms namespace had that Application class... it's totally unrelated to Forms.

Comment: LOL - yeah, I do not use it either. Odd spot to find it.

Comment: Actually, the Application class is exclusively related to Forms, in that the Application.Run method is what initiates the main window message loop that processes all window (a.k.a. "form") events.  It also contains DoEvents() which allows the window to process pending events while inside a handler.  This should all be familiar to anyone who programmed the Win32 API prior to the invention of .NET.