# Finding my main executable's path using Assembly vs AppDomain

Tags: .net, path, directory, exe

I'm a .NET user, and my goal is as simple as finding the absolute path of the directory of my main executing assembly (the EXE file).

I have several candidates:

- `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase`
- `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`
- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

If to judge by the .NET documentation - I'm leaning towards `CodeBase`.
Can anyone shed light over all three in a bit more specific terms than the .NET documentation? An example to demonstrate the difference perhaps?

Comment: I've found [this post](http://knitinr.blogspot.it/2008/07/systemreflection-get-this-assembly.html) as a good explanation of the different Assembly methods.

Answer (score 17):

I would use `GetEntryAssembly()` instead of `GetExecutingAssembly()`.

To see why, do this:

- Create a new Console Project
- Add a class library project (`ClassLibrary1`) to the solution and reference it from the Console Project.

Put this in `ClassLibrary1`:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Reflection;

    public class Class1
    {
        public void GetInfo(int n)
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            Console.WriteLine("[GetEntryAssembly {0}] Location:{1}", n, Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.Location));
            asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Console.WriteLine("[GetExecutingAssembly() {0}] Location:{1}", n, Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.Location));
        }
    }
}
```

Put this in console's `Program.cs`:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Reflection;
    using ClassLibrary1;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            Console.WriteLine("[GetEntryAssembly() 1] Location:{0}", Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.Location));
            asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Console.WriteLine("[GetExecutingAssembly() 1] Location:{0}", Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.Location));

            Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
            obj1.GetInfo(2);

            asm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\temp\ClassLibrary1.dll");
            Type t = asm.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Class1");
            object obj2 = asm.CreateInstance("ClassLibrary1.Class1");
            t.GetMethod("GetInfo").Invoke(obj2, new object[] { 3 });

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Build the solution, copy `ClassLibrary1.dll` to `c:\temp` and run.

As you will see, `GetExecutingAssembly()` may trick you in certain conditions.

One last note, if your app is a Windows Forms one, you can just use `Application.ExecutablePath`.

Comment: Good one, thanks, I adopt the change!
But how about Assembly.CodeBase vs AppDomain.BaseDirectory?

Comment: It'd be nice if you posted the output instead of making one compile and run it to see your point :-)

Comment: Assembly.GetEntryAssembly is not reliable, specifically it will return null if the application started in an unmanaged context instead of a managed context.  The result must be null checked.

Comment: outpout is :

[GetEntryAssembly() 1] Location:C:\Users\bob\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\myapp\myapp\bin\Debug
[GetExecutingAssembly() 1] Location:C:\Users\bob\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\myapp\myapp\bin\Debug

[GetEntryAssembly() 2] Location:C:\Users\bob\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\myapp\myapp\bin\Debug
[GetExecutingAssembly()2] Location:C:\Users\bob\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\myapp\myapp\bin\Debug

[GetEntryAssembly() 3] Location:C:\Users\bob\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\myapp\myapp\bin\Debug
[GetExecutingAssembly() 3] Location:C:\temp

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure about `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`, but the difference between `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase` and `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` was explained [in this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/06/26/57198.aspx).

> The CodeBase is a URL to the place where the file was found, while the Location is the path from where it was actually loaded. For example, if the assembly was downloaded from the internet, its CodeBase may start with "http://", but its Location may start with "C:\". If the file was shadow copied, the Location would be the path to the copy of the file in the shadow-copy dir.
>
> It’s also good to know that the CodeBase is not guaranteed to be set for assemblies in the GAC. Location will always be set for assemblies loaded from disk, however.

So it seems your best bet is `Location` if you need the real directory the file was executed from.

Comment: Actually with shadow-copy unit tests and some files copied to output you may want to use CodeBase (parsed via Uri class) for the exact same reason.

Comment: Just in case anyone else wonders: GAC means [Global Assembly Cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) :)

Comment: The blog post link no longer takes you to the blog post

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, all the methods above can fail if you use a virtualization like XenoCode postbuild. 
I have tested many methods and found another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980202/how-do-i-find-the-current-executable-filename/2848696#2848696). 
I've found that only the

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe"
```

returns the correct filename of the executable.
So combining the filename with the path from `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` you will get the correct path of the executable.

Comment: This will return the development server filename in asp.net ;)

Comment: Of cause, this is a main executing assembly in the ASP.NET

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName; for the exe path on .net over AppDomain.

Comment: This seems to be the real answer since, as in my case, Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() can be null.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.codebase.aspx

**Assembly.CodeBase**

> To get the absolute path to the loaded
>   manifest-containing file, use the
>   `Assembly.Location` property instead.
>
> If the assembly was loaded as a byte
>   array, using an overload of the Load
>   method that takes an array of bytes,
>   this property returns the location of
>   the caller of the method, not the
>   location of the loaded assembly.

For `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`, I honestly have no idea about the differences from a practical point of view.

Comment: I actually need where the exe file was intended to be executed from, and not it's actual location, so I guess I'll stick with CodeBase :) thanks for the pointer though.

Answer (score -4):

Use System.Linq

```
string MainExecutablePath= (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().First(P =>P.MainWindowTitle == "MainExecutable'sWindowName")).MainModule.FileName.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Improvements: Linq can be replaced with `GetCurrentProcess()` (as mentioned by @Shurup), and FileName is already a string so no need for `ToString()` :)
So: `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName`