# Extracting the current executable name

Tags: c++, windows

Firstly, I would like to say that I don't mean the full path, what
GetModuleFileName or argv[0] yield. Is there a smarter solution than dismissing everything before the last backslash?

Comment: What platform are you on? I suppose Windows?

Comment: What's is wrong with taking everything after the last path delimiter?  Myself, I just use my own written basename function on argv[0].

Comment: There are also path functions to do it.

Comment: Luka, you supposed correctly, tags weren't added accidentally ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all you want to get hold of the full path to the executable by calling [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx) passing `NULL` as the module handle. Then call [`PathFindFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773589.aspx) to pull out the file name component.

There is in fact a difference between `GetModuleFileName` and `argv[0]`. The latter is the name used to start the process. It could be missing the full path, but more importantly here, it could be missing the `.exe` extension. If you want to know the actual filename then you need to use `GetModuleFileName`.

Comment: That's what I was trying to find. I find it *really* funny how that example uses `void main` though. Seriously, Microsoft?

Comment: Microsoft is allowed to do it like that because they write the compiler. As such they can make use compiler specific extension that you and I (as good standards following citizens) can't.

Answer (score 0):

If you use .NET, then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980202/how-do-i-find-the-current-executable-filename)'s an answer. But internally it may be calling `GetModuleFileName`.

Comment: I don't use .NET. It's Windows api project.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows C/C++ there is a global variable `extern char * _pgmptr` that can be read as well as an unsafe string copy from `_get_pgmptr(char ** buffer)`.

**Caveats**

> Only call [_get_pgmptr()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/get-pgmptr?view=vs-2019) if your program has a narrow entry point, like main() or WinMain(). The _pgmptr global variable contains the full path to the executable associated with the process. For more information, see [_pgmptr, _wpgmptr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/pgmptr-wpgmptr?view=vs-2019).
>
> If a DLL is loaded in two processes, its file name in one process may differ in case from its file name in the other process.
>
> The global variable _pgmptr is automatically initialized to the full path of the executable file, and can be used to retrieve the full path name of an executable file.