# How to retrive relative path of executable file

Tags: c#, c++, windows, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the application executable name in Windows (C++ Win32 or C++/CLI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124886/how-to-get-the-application-executable-name-in-windows-c-win32-or-c-cli)
>   [Extracting the current executable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572560/extracting-the-current-executable-name)

I need to get the relative path of the executable file directory using C++. I have done the same program using C# which works perfectly.

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath)
```

I would like to get the similar result using C++.

Comment: thank you.ill look in to those questions

Answer (score 0):

Using boost::filesystem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    path p(argv[0]);

    cout << p.parent_path() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```