# How do I launch an exe that's in the same subfolder as the main one? (C++)

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++

I'm working on a program download manager with options to open the app you've downloaded.

You can download an app and it would be here:
`.../programfiles/pub/appmanager/apps/APPHERE.exe`
And the main program would be in
`.../programfiles/pub/appmanager/MAINFILE.EXE`

I need to find a way to start the app. As seen below, i've tried many ways of doing it (`system`, ect).
(also `system()` only opens apps in the same directory so i could do something there). 
I can do a separate application, but if someone knows how to implement it into a `.NET` gui, that would be helpful

I tried:
`ShellExecute, System, Create Process`
 (help me on this one im confused)

EDIT:
I need it so that it makes the full directory.

I try something like :
`system(app/pxws.exe)`
and it wont work

and i tried to merge strings with getmaindirectory and it says not found

Comment: Read up on "current working directory" and "absolute" vs "relative" paths. There's obviously something there you don't grok 100%

Comment: Ill try @JesperJuhl I'm a bit new to managing files

Comment: Also, on Windows use backslash as path divider.

Comment: @SidS Double Backslash or one

Comment: Double, if it is part of a string literal.

Comment: Ok, im updating my question as i realize i need to be in more depth with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a new path that is relative to the EXE of the current process, you can do the following:

- Retrieve the calling process's full EXE path via [`GetModuleFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamew) or [.NET equivilent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980202/).
- Strip off the filename portion (`MAINFILE.EXE`) using [`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname?view=netframework-4.8).
- Append the desired relative path segment (`apps/APPHERE.exe`) using [`System.IO.Path.Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8).

Then you can use the new path with whatever API you need.

Comment: I'll test this, if it doesn't work ill comment here